# When does the GC take action

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I wonder what are the situations of the GC to free the memory of a pointer.

For example:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<int> list1;

    public void test()
    {
        List<int> list2 = new list<int>();

        list2.Add(1);
        list2.Add(1);

        list1 = list2;
    }
}
```

The GC was suppose to free the memory of list2, does it because another element share the same address of list2? After the run of test()

What are the situations which the G will free the memory of an element.

Comment: list2 won't be collected by GC since it is being referenced by list1..Basically GC would walk through the graph and collect objects which are not reachable..In your case list1 and list2 are reachable and hence won't be collected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you create list2 as a local variable, but then you retain the reference to the underlying object in list1 before the method exits, which means the object you created in test() won't be collected (until list1 gets out of scope or changes the reference). Your object is ready to be collected only when there are no **strong** references to it (read about weak references if you want to know more on this subject).

Even when the object is ready to be collected, garbage collector will only run when:

- There is low physical memory (OS will tell your app when there is memory pressure)
- Memory used by allocated objects surpasses a certain threshold which is adjusted dynamically
- New allocation cannot be made because not enough memory available
- GC.Collect() was called explicitly
- ..

Answer (score 1):

`list1` retains a reference to the list after test() completes and will retain that reference for the lifetime of the instance of `Test`. The GC will not free up that list therefore until sometime after there is no longer any reference to `Test`.

When that "sometime after" occurs can be viewed as non-deterministic. It'll do it as and when it wants to. It almost certainly won't do it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

> does it because another element caught the address if list2?

No, it because `list2` is no longer available out of scope of `test(..)` method.

Worth mantioning, that the *pointer* becomes invalid, but the *memory* it refers to is still "alive". Because there is another `list1` that refers to the same memory

```
list1 = list2;
```

and `list1` is a global var, so is not subject for destruction in *this concrete case*.

And more: it's not a must that `GC` actually frees a memory. Correct to say that the memory is *marked* to be garbage collected, but will be it *actually*  cleaned or not is subject of other validations.

Answer (score 1):

.NET GC is a [tracing, generational, mark-and-sweep collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Tracing_garbage_collectors).

It will never collect objects which are *reachable*, where reachable objects are ones:

1. which are referenced from anywhere in the call stack (that is, all local variables and parameters in the functions currently being invoked), and any global variables. These objects are called *roots*.
2. which are referenced by other reachable objects.

In your case, the `new List<int>()` statement creates a new list instance in memory, which is initially referenced by `list2`. If you didn't assign it to `list1`, it would have been eligible for collection as soon as `list2` went out of scope (and then collected some time in the future).

Since you made your `list1` field reference that same instance, after leaving the `test1` method you are still left with a strong reference to that (one and only) object instance.

Comment: The .Net GC is generational. It does not suffer from immutability as a mark-and-sweep system would.

Comment: @Gusdor: well, the algorithm is still "mark and sweep", once it starts processing a certain generation. But you're right, the fact that it's mark-and-sweep doesn't really change what it's supposed to do (collect non-reachable objects).

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is a bit mixed so I'll try to correct that.

Firstly, the GC runs automatically and asynchronously. It is also 'smart'. It will only run when required, to minimize the number of collection attempts. You should never have to interact with it.

> The GC was suppose to free the memory of list2, does it because
>   another element caught the address if list2? After the run of test()

`list1` is a class *member*. `list2` is a *local variable*. `list1` is always `null` - there is nothing to collect. A *reference* (**no** pointers in c#!) to `list2` is created when you assign it to `list1`. `list2` will now only be created when the class `Test` is collected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the GC will remove the content of list2 because it is kept alive for only a short amount of time, due to it living on the stack and not the heap.

So, if you're wondering if the GC clears it because you've assigned list1=list2, then no. List2 would be kept alive as well but it gets killed off due to the method ending. :)

Here is a small blogpost that goes a bit more in-depth on the GC: http://it-ca.net/blogdylan/?p=354